# Wine As Root Service

Tags: wine

I have a service that runs a Java program as root. The Java program may start a Wine process.

The obvious problem is, I cannot run `wine` as `root`. For some security reason, even though my machine is locked down in EC2 VPC behind VPN & Firewall & Bastion & Security Groups.

I thought I could make a `.wine` folder in `/home/ubuntu/.wine` and set `WINEPREFIX` to that, however it doesn't work either.

Do you have any suggestions how to run `wine` while under `root` ?

- I have access to different folders.
- I cannot change the original service user (`root`).

Thanks!

Comment: IT Security 101: If it's a Java process running things as `root`, it should *not* be using Wine.  Wine as `root` opens your system to all the evils of Windows viruses - not that standard Wine deployments won't do this, but they'll usually get stuck within non-administrator permissions, rather than 'i can access the whole system'.  I strongly recommend you ***do not*** try to use this software if it's opening you to such risks.

Comment: I second  Thomas Ward's  statement but congrats on finding your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I got the fix - make a symlink, as proposed on [bugs.winehq.org](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30647):

```
sudo ln -s /home/ubuntu/.wine /root/wine
```

Comment: Was a last resort, didn't think it would work.